# Qjson get object name

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qjson

I have a json object how can I get object name ?
I can't have object name it will be sent by server and that way I should get the object names.

```
{
    "success":1,
    "return":{
        "343152":{//get this object name
            "pair":"usd_eur",
            "type":"sell",
            "amount":1.00000000,
            "rate":3.00000000,
            "timestamp_created":1342448420,
            "status":0
        }
                "343157":{//get this object name
            "pair":"usd_eur",
            "type":"sell",
            "amount":1.00000000,
            "rate":3.00000000,
            "timestamp_created":1342448420,
            "status":0
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the json support in QtCore 5.X or the third-party qjson library? Also, which qt are you using?

Comment: I gave a +1 because I think the json support in QtCore is relatively new, and it is always good to get more examples, but really :), I do not suggest using qjson if you are not planning to target Qt 4, and even if you did, I would suggest to backport this json feature if it is not yet done. The reason is that it is maintained by a third-party entity rather than the Qt Project, so it will probably get less commit and work, and also, based on Thiago's benchmark, it is lotta slower. Personally, I do not like it is explicit parser API much either. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your post was tagged with qjson, I assume you're using it...

```
QJson::Parser parser;
bool ok;
QVariantMap result = parser.parse (json, &ok).toMap(); // json is a QByteArray w. the data
QVariantMap returnMap = result["return"].toMap();

// iterate your map to get the names you're interested in.
for(QVariantMap::const_iterator iter = returnMap.begin(); iter != returnMap.end(); ++iter) {
    qDebug() << iter.key();
}

// Do whatever you need with yourObj..
```

See http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/

Comment: ,I dont have "343152" I neet to get "343152" in json how can I get "343152"?

Comment: Updated my answer.  You need to iterate `returnMap`

Comment: It is not OK IMHO because the OP is using Qt 5... QJson is many times slower, and it is better to use the official supported feature written by Lars, the current chief maintainer of the Qt Project. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the json support in QtCore with version >= 5.X. You can do that with the following code:

#### json.txt

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "return": {
        "343152": {
            "pair": "usd_eur",
            "type": "sell",
            "amount": 1.00000000,
            "rate": 3.00000000,
            "timestamp_created": 1342448420,
            "status": 0
        },

        "343157": {
            "pair": "usd_eur",
            "type": "sell",
            "amount ":1.00000000,
            "rate": 3.00000000,
            "timestamp_created": 1342448420,
            "status": 0
        }
    }
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QJsonParseError>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

int main()
{
    QFile file("json.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "File open error:" << file.errorString();
        return 1;
    }

    QByteArray jsonByteArray = file.readAll();

    file.close();

    QJsonParseError jsonParseError;
    QJsonDocument jsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonByteArray, &jsonParseError);
    if (jsonParseError.error != QJsonParseError::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Error happened:" << jsonParseError.errorString();
        return 1;
    }

    if (!jsonDocument.isObject()) {
        qDebug() << "The json data is not an object";
        return 1;
    }

    QJsonObject mainJsonObject(jsonDocument.object());

    QJsonValue returnJsonValue = mainJsonObject.value(QStringLiteral("return"));

    if (!returnJsonValue.isObject()) {
        qDebug() << "The json data is not an object";
        return 1;
    }

    qDebug() << "KEYS WANTED:" << returnJsonValue.toObject().keys();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

> g++ -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -I/usr/include -lQt5Core main.cpp && ./a.out

```
KEYS WANTED: ("343152", "343157")
```

Comment: thank you this also work too like qvariantmap iterator.